# How many processes are created in the program when using fork() in a condition?

Tags: while-loop, operating-system, fork, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble to understand how fork() works when it is used as a condition. I know that fork() creates a child process as an exact copy of the parent process. My question is, how many processes are created in the following program? Here is the code:

```
int global = 0;
int main() {
    while(global < 5 && !fork()) {
        sleep(1);
        global += 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", global);
    return 0;
}
```

I was a assuming that for each fork() call, every process that is already running will create a child process and continue like that as long as the variable global reaches the value of 5.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @MartinJames It prints out 5 as the value of global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fork()` call returns 0 in the child and the `pid` of the child in the parent.

Therefore, in the parent, the second condition will evaluate to 0, and the loop will exit and then print. In the child, the second condition will evaluate to non-zero, and the loop will fork again with a higher value of global (which is inherited).

Thus, we will see a total of 5 new processes in addition to the parent.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but the "the loop will exit without printing" seems wrong to me. It should exit the loop and print, shouldn't it?

Comment: Either I misread the original question or it had been edited.  I'll correct this when I get to a computer.  Thanks!